# How to get default dialler app name on my phone with termux

Tags: android, bash, termux

I have created a bash script  which  reads notifications with command `termux-notification-list`  i used while loop to read continuously.
So when I recieve a call this script will read the notification of default dialler app and search for the phone number with  my npm package  [truecallerjs](https://github.com/sumithemmadi/truecallerjs) and sends  a notification with the name of the person who holds that number.
see the  below  screenshot

[image]

so, Im  using mi phone which has `com.android.incallui`  as a default dialler app . see this below link, my script send phone number details  when there is a notification from `com.android.incallui` .
https://github.com/sumithemmadi/truecaller-on-termux/blob/main/run#L52
the script will work only if the user is using  mi phone for other phones there will be different dialer app.

So how can I get default dialler app.

See i have used

```sh
 ...
   if [[ $packageName == "com.android.incallui"  ]]
   then
...
```

It should be like

```sh
 ...
   if [[ $packageName == "[Default dialer app name]"  ]]
   then
...
```

What ever the default dialer  user use , [Default dialer app name] should be the name of the app which will receive calls.
If the user uses the google dialer it should be

```sh
 ...
   if [[ $packageName == "com.google.android.dialer"  ]]
   then
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android `>= 10`, grant termux DUMP permission with `adb shell pm grant com.termux android.permission.DUMP` and then run `/system/bin/dumpsys role | grep -A 1 android.app.role.DIALER | grep holders= | sed -E 's/[ \t]+holders=(.*)/\1/'`

You may get an array if more than one app assigned the role.

For android `< 10` you can run `cmd package resolve-activity tel://123456` with adb or root.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/227155/retrieve-list-of-default-apps-via-adb

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r32:packages/modules/Permission/service/java/com/android/role/RoleService.java;l=735

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r32:packages/modules/Permission/service/java/com/android/role/RoleUserState.java;l=384;bpv=0;bpt=1

You can get android version with `/system/bin/getprop ro.build.version.sdk`.

https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/discussions/9987#discussioncomment-2556377